# What is the command to include an image in a file such that this image becomes like a page

Tags: books, includegraphics

What is the command to include an image in a file such that this image becomes like a page.

**My problem**

I may have written a book. For the next page

[image]

Instead of this page being simple, I want to include the following image in writing

[image]

Comment: You want the image to cover the entire 8.5" x 11" page?

Comment: `pdfpages` package?